# Conditional evaluating to a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a check that looks to see if a field has changed from the placeholder value. If it hasn't I reassign the original `changed` value, as the function (in my actual codebase) has to look at multiple fields.

I'm just a bit confused why:

`changed = (locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder) ? true : changed;`

is evaluating to an empty string* if the field is submitted with no value.

**output at end of post*

I assume it's the empty value of `locationField.value`, but shouldn't it be assigning either 'true' or the value of changed? Changed (as far as I can see) is never, and should never, be a string.

Probably a simple question, but I can't see the answer.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/WNMpVGv?editors=1011)

```js
const locationField = document.querySelector('.location');
const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
let changed = false;

submit.addEventListener('click', e => {
  changed = (locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder) ? true : changed;
  console.log(locationField.value, locationField.placeholder, (locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder));
  console.log(changed);
  
  // reset 
  changed = false;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test" class="location">
<button class="submit">Submit</button>
```

*****EDIT:***

Results I get:

input "changed" => `"changed", "test", true`

input "test" => `"test", "test", false`

input "" `"", "test", ""`, when I'd expect `"", "test", false`

Comment: "*is evaluating to an empty string if the field is submitted with no value.*" Can you clarify this? When I submit without modifying the field's value, I got `test` and `false` logged in the console - no empty string here.

Comment: I get `"", "test", ""` and then `false`. Which means that (in that first `console.log()`) `(locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder))` is evaluating to "" - which I think is causing me issues

Comment: if I change the value I get `"changed", "test", true`, if I type "test" I get `"test", "test", false`, but if I leave it empty I get `"", "test", ""`, when I'd expect `"", "test", false`

Comment: Ah, gotcha - a bit of an oversight for that output on my part. Apologies!

Comment: No worries, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Logical AND (&&) evaluates operands from left to right, returning immediately with the value of the first falsy operand it encounters; if all values are truthy, the value of the last operand is returned.

(source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

So in your case, if `locationField.value` is "" which evaluates as a falsy value, then logical AND going to return the value of  `locationField.value` (which is why it returns an empty string)

Comment: Wow, didn't know it returned the value rather than what it evaluated to. So I guess `!!locationField.value` will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I've been bitten by this issue in the past myself. :P

Comment: Just to double check - It's evaluating `locationField.value` to `""`, then assigning that to `changed` *then* returning the result of the ternary? So `true` or `""`? That is definitely not the order I'd assume it was evaluating the expression!!

Comment: Assuming `locationField.value = “”`, 
`(locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder) ? true : changed` will return the value of `changed` since `“”` evaluates as falsy.  In the following line where you are outputting the result of `(locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder)`, it will output `“”` since locationField.value is the first falsy operand.

Answer (score 2):

If you first convert `locationField.value` to a boolean, either with `!!` or with `Boolean()`, then you should get the expected result.

```js
(!!locationField.value && locationField.value !== locationField.placeholder)
```